# Error in if statement in r

Tags: r, if-statement

This might be a silly question, but since I could not find the way to search it, I wanted to ask. I have the code below:

(m is a numeric value defined earlier)

```
if (0 < m <= 1.00){  
    print("a") 
  } else if (1.00 < m <= 2.00){  
      print("likely benign")
  } else if (2.00 < m <= 3.00){  
      print("b") 
  }   else if (3.00 < m <= 4.00){  
      print("c") 
  }   else if (4.00 < m <= 5.00){  
      print("d") 
  }   else if (5.00 < m <= 6.00){ 
      print("e")
  }   else{  
      print("f") 
  }
```

It gives the error:

> Error: unexpected '}' in " }"

but I used if in exactly the same way on the upper part of the code and there is no error from that part. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the syntax `0 < m <= 1.00`  Try with `0 < m & m <= 1.00`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to change the syntax to `&`

```
 if(0 < m & m <= 1.00){
   ---
```

and also in all the `else if` conditions.

It is not clear whether `m` is of length 1 or >1.  If it is length 1, use the `&` and if greater than 1, it may be better to use `ifelse` instead of `if/else` or if we are using `if/else`, use `&&` instead of `&` as @ZheyuanLi suggested in the comments.